# render dynamic value from passport.socketio to jade view

Tags: node.js, pug, passport.js

I'm relatively new to node and socketio. What I'm trying to achieve is authenticate users using passport and send total number logged user count to the view. Such that if a logged in user can see the total number of current-logged-in users and if a user logs that the count decreases or increases when someone else log-ins respectively.

Using passport.socketio to access authenticated passport user information from a socket.io connection.

In the callback, I'm storing the username in a mongoose collection, and accordingly on the logout removing the user from the collection. I get a count of the number of users in the model which I need to pass and bind to the view. Jade being the template engine. Below is how my onAuthorizeSuccess callback looks like where I try to pass the count to home.jade.

```
function onAuthorizeSuccess(data, accept) {

    var username = data.user.username;

    var User = mongoose.model('loggedusers', userSchema);

    var user = new User({
        username: username
    });

    user.save(function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
            console.log('Saved : ', data);
        }

        User.count({}, function (err, c) {
            console.log('Count is ' + c);

            app.get('/', function (req, res) {

                res.render('home', {
                    count: {
                        countData: c
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    });

    console.log('successful connection to socket.io ');

    accept(); //Let the user through
}
```

And in the jade view I try to set it using

```
li Logged Users ---> #{countData.c}
```

But, countData is undefined in the view.

How should I go about rendering a dynamic value from the server to the view in jade?

Any assistance much appreciated.

Thanks,
Arnab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable is wrong you should use instead `#{count}` with:

```
res.render('home', {count: c});
```

Comment: Thanks! @Michelem 
I did change it to 
    #{count.countData}

But, it still is undefined in the view
Cannot read property 'countData' of undefined

Comment: Yes because you should first define the object, better if you use direct `{count: c}`, I'm updating the answer

Comment: Thanks! I had tried {count: c} earlier as well. But, the value does not seem to pass to the view.

When I log the value in the console.
i.e. console.log('count is '+c); 
I do get the value in the console. But, res.render('home', {count: c}); does not pass the value, and the view stays blank

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.

Made a function to server content over a socket, that the control helps updating on the front-end

```
module.exports = function (socket) {

setInterval(function () {

var UserSchema = require('mongoose').model('loggedusers');

UserSchema.count({}, function(err, c){

    console.log('Count is ' + c);
    socket.emit('send:count', {
        count: c
    });

   });
}, 1000);
};
```

And the angular controller
    angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
    controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, socket) {
    socket.on('send:count', function (data) {
    $scope.count = data.count;
    });
    });

and in jade `{{count}}` and add `div.container(ng-controller='AppCtrl')` should give the updated count on the front-end.

Arnab